# Get and set Assembly Parameter

Tags: c#, revit-api

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I've got a list of my selected elements:

```
        public IList<Element> SelectElement(UIDocument uiDoc, Document doc)
    {
            List<Element> values = new List<Element>();
        try
        {
            IList<Reference> reference = uiDoc.Selection.PickObjects(ObjectType.Element);
            foreach (Reference r in reference)
            {
               Element el = doc.GetElement(r);
               Category bc = doc.GetElement(r).Category;
                if(el is FabricationPart)
                {
                    values.Add(el);
                }
                if (el is AssemblyInstance)
                {
                    values.Add(el);
                }
            }              
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            TaskDialog td = new TaskDialog("Selection");
            td.MainContent = "No Elements Have Been Selected";
            td.Show(); 
        }
        return values;
    }
```

And from this list of elements I create another list casting the selection to elements and go through each element and get/set the parameters:

```
            List<Element> e = (List<Element>)SelectElement(uiDoc, doc);
        foreach (Element element in e)
{ Parameter p = element.LookupParameter("TPFullFabricationServiceName");

//Do Some Stuff...
}
```

This works fine for regular elements in the model but doesnt work for parameters of the assemblies. This is what works for the fabrication parts:

```
                        if (element.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.FABRICATION_PRODUCT_DATA_PRODUCT).AsString().ToString() == "Pipe" ||
                        element.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.FABRICATION_PRODUCT_DATA_PRODUCT).AsString().ToString() == "Tee" ||
                        element.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.FABRICATION_PRODUCT_DATA_PRODUCT).AsString().ToString() == "Elbow")
                    {
                        p.Set(element.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.FABRICATION_SERVICE_NAME).AsString());
                    }
```

Some of the parameters are bound to the fabrication parts category while others are bound to the assemblies category. Do I have to access the assemblies differently?

Comment: I suggest being much more specific in your question, and providing more specific code. For example, iIn the code above, you seem to be filtering for `FabricationPart`; what does that have to do with assemblies? What parameter are you trying to set? I see mention of "TPSpoolWeight", and also `BuiltInParameter.FABRICATION_PART_WEIGHT`. I am confused.

Comment: I'm getting the builtin parameters, doing some stuff depending on the scenario such as adding the total number of connections within an assembly for a specific pipe type such as steel pipe with weld connections and adding the total amount of weld inches, then putting that total into a parameter for the assembly. I updated what I have in the code as well.

Answer (score 1):

All Revit `Parameter` value objects on the `Element` class are treated identically. Reading and writing parameter values is completely generic and does not depend on the element type.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out. I split it into two methods instead of trying to edit parameters for both fabrication parts and assemblies in the same method.
This is what I did for the assemblies:

```
        private void SetAssemblyInstanceParameters(AssemblyInstance assemblyInstance)
    {
        Parameter p2 = assemblyInstance.LookupParameter("TPSpoolWeight");

        using (Transaction t = new Transaction(assemblyInstance.Document, "Set Parameters"))
        {
            t.Start();

            p2.Set(20);

            t.Commit();
        }
 
    }
```

Then I called both the set assemblies method and the fabrication parts method after checking what the selected element is:

```
                List<Element> selectedElements = (List<Element>)SelectElement(uiDoc, doc);

            using (TransactionGroup transactionGroup = new TransactionGroup(doc))
            {
                transactionGroup.Start("Set Parameters");

                foreach (Element element in selectedElements)
                {
                    if (element is FabricationPart fabricationPart)
                    {
                        SetFabricationPartParameters(fabricationPart);
                    }
                    else if (element is AssemblyInstance assemblyInstance)
                    {
                        SetAssemblyInstanceParameters(assemblyInstance);
                    }
                }
                transactionGroup.Assimilate();
            }
```

There still may be a better way to do this but this is how I solved it.